# Is there any way to restore an Excel file to a previous version?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

Is it possible to roll back changes I made by mistake in Excel 2007? The Windows 7 system protection option was disabled.

Comment: Could you be more explicit ?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have backups, then there you go.
2. If you used "Save version" functionality, you can open previous version.

Otherwise you are out of luck, unless you didn't close Excel (and that file). In that case, you can just undo your changes (Edit->Undo, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>).